# Prolog Predicades Relation

Tags: prolog

I studing prolog and i got issues to resolve this exercise:

I need to create a a method that I call Relation(Variable, List of List)

EX:

```
list(a,b) 
list(c,b)
list(c,h)
```

Return should be all the list that contains the variable Relation(c,X)

```
X= [[c,b],[c,h]]
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please show samples of code that you've tried to do this.  We're happy to help with coding issues, but we're not a code writing service.

Comment: This is very simple if you read some documentation on SWI Prolog predicates. See, for example, `findall/3`.

Comment: Here is what is currenlty working to check the list

_exist(E,[E|_H])._
_exist(E,[H|T]):-exist(E,T)._

this will work if i type exist(a,[a,v,n,e,k)
will return true , now im trying to load an entire list of list from predicates 

exist(a,list) , so that will grab all the list i add on .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to the question :

```
check(_,[],X). 
check(Var,[H|T],[H|X]):-member(Var,H),check(Var,T,X). 
check(Var,[_|T],X):-check(Var,T,X).
```

Only that im not sure how to use the setof/3 procedure , since i need to load the predicates like this

```
list(a,b)
list(b,c)
list(c,t)
```